# Z-index between absolute and a relative div (all browser)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the positioning between absolute and relative div.

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul style="position: absolute; z-index:10">menu</ul>

<div id="box-img" style="position: relative; z-index:9">
    <div style="position: absolute"></div>
</div>
```

The UL tag appears below the "box-img" DIV, although it has a higher z-index property. Why?

If I remove the relative position in the "box-img" DIV then the UL tag appears over.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [I can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/rTN5W/)

Answer (score 1):

In IE, whenever you apply the position CSS rule to an element, it generates a new stacking context within that element. That means that z-index will only be properly respected within that element's children and children in other stacking contexts with lower z-indexes may still stack above.

See here: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html